Relation between homogeneous ODE of degree n and Euler's theorem on homogeneous equations
I understand the intuition behind Euler's theorem on homogeneous equations, which is related to "radial derivative"  (See Intuition about Euler's Theorem on homogeneous equations). The 2-dimensional version of the theorem asserts that if f(x,y) satisfacies $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$ (a function like this it is called homogeneous of degree n), then $n*f(x,y)=(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(x,y)$.
On the other hand, if $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ are homogeneous of degree $n$, then the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ can be solved via $u=y/x$ which gives an ODE of separation of variable type.
Is there a context where this kind of ODE is studied? what is the interpretation of this kind of ODE? is it related with something about "radial derivative"?
I hope my questions are well understood.
Thanks
